# Pull a value from a column when a checkbox (in another column) is check

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

Intermediate programmer here using Visual Studio 2010 and doing all in VB not C#.

Have a 15-column GridView1. Auto-Select takes up the [0] column. Column [1] have a JobNumber value which is different for each row. Column [14] has a template field with a single CheckBox1 per row.

I need to get the value from Column [1] if Column [14] is checked. I can get the occurrence of the checkbox using this code:

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    Dim result As Boolean = DirectCast(row.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked
Next
```

This code does work to find which row has a checked box. The problem, which I haven't found an answer to is as the code runs and the rows are found, how do I get the value displayed in Column [1} for each of the rows found to have a checked box?

Its probably been answered prior to this question of mine but I may have terminology wrong and am just asking the wrong question.

Thanks all!

Comment: Using the code as you suggested, I rewrote to this For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

            Dim myLIst As New List(Of String)
            'Find the rows that are checked
            Dim result As Boolean = DirectCast(row.FindControl("CheckBox_Assign"), CheckBox).Checked
            'If a row has a checked box get the value of the [1] cell
            If result = True Then
                myLIst.Add(row.Cells(1).Text)
            End If
            'See if you got anything
            Response.Write(myLIst)
        Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tampering the least possible with your code, might this work?

```
    Dim myList As New List(Of String)
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim result As Boolean = DirectCast(row.FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked
        If result Then myList.Add(row.Cells(1).Text)
    Next
    'myList will now contain desired values
```

Comment: When I Response.Write(myLIst) to see what the code pulled out, I get this for each checkbox checked ... System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]. I have never had to use myList and am not sure I am using it correctly now. Any further help to pull cell [1] value on a row where's its column with a checkbox is selected? Thanks

Comment: Ok, what's the name of the control in column [1]?

Comment: We make panel forming machines. Each machine has an job number (I.D. number) formatted like [26650.000]. GridView1 displays all machines not shipped yet with these job numbers (one per row) in Cell[1]. Info comes from a SQL db table called [JobMast] and from a column called [JobNum]. It isn't a huge display with anywhere from 40 to 100 machines listed at a time in GridView1. Once desired checkboxes are checked, I use a button click to start another table's update process with the job numbers I just collected.  Hope that explains what your were asking for. Thanks for all help.

Comment: Figured it out. Using your initial code as a guide I did a [Dim JNRetrieved As String] and followed that with [JNRetrieved = Trim(row.Cells(1).Text)]. Pulled the value out of the cell and I'm off and running. Seems like the easiest tasks are the hardest ones to figure out because they're easy. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: Glad you did it :-)